# Camel need Non-blocking Queue - Analogous to not processing events on graphics thread

Tags: apache-camel

Sorry I answered my own question - it actually IS just SEDA, I assumed when I saw 'BlockingQueue' that SEDA would block until the queue had been read ... which of course is nonsense. SEDA is completely all I need. Question answered

---

I've got a problem that's compeletely screwing me, I've been provided a custom Endpoint by company we connect to, but the endpoint maintains a heart-beat to a feed, and when it sends messages above a certain size they take so long to process on the route that its blocking and the heartbeat gets lost and the connection goes down

Obviously this is analogous to processing events on a non-graphics thread to keep a smooth operation going. But I'm unsure how I'd achieve this in camel. Essentially I want to queue the results and have them on a separate thread.

```
from( "custom:endpoint" )
.process( MyProcesor )
.to( "some-endpoint")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested [camel-seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) is a simple way to perform async/mult-threaded processing, beware that the blocking queues are in-memory only (lost if VM is stopped, etc).  if you need guaranteed messaging support, use [camel-jms](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)